# TFS path after moving folder not mapped between branches

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I'm new to tfs, but let's say I have two branches, **dev** and **test**.

Recently I moved a subfolder to another parent in **dev**. Now when trying to merge this subfolder (with its new location) into test, it seems to be still pointing towards its old location.

For example, before moving folder:
*dev/../Parent1/Subfolder*

After moving:
dev/../Parent2/Subfolder

Now when trying to merge *Subfolder* with **Test**, I get the old target branch location in the list, i.e. *test/../Parent1/Subfolder*.

Not really sure what to do about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Tested at my side, everything works correctly.

Just check below items to narrow down the issue:

- Make sure the sources (both branches) are correctly in source
  control.
- Make sure you merged from **Dev** to the right **Test** branch but
  not other branches.
- Make sure you select the **Latest Version** to merge but not the old
  version which before moving the sub-folder.

[image]